Unable to install strongswan in Ubuntu 22.04
I am trying to re-install strongswan in ubuntu 22.
Ran the following commands
$ sudo apt update
Hit:1 https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu focal InRelease
Hit:2 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy InRelease
Hit:3 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates InRelease
Hit:4 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-backports InRelease
Hit:5 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security InRelease
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
All packages are up to date.

$ sudo apt upgrade
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
Get more security updates through Ubuntu Pro with 'esm-apps' enabled:
 libldns3 libpostproc55 libavcodec58 libavutil56 libswscale5 libswresample3
 libavformat58 libavfilter7
Learn more about Ubuntu Pro at https://ubuntu.com/pro
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.

$ sudo apt-get install strongswan
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
libreswan : Conflicts: ike-server
            Conflicts: strongswan-libcharon but 5.9.5-2ubuntu2.2 is to be installed
            Conflicts: strongswan-starter but 5.9.5-2ubuntu2.2 is to be installed
E: Error, pkgProblemResolver::Resolve generated breaks, this may be caused by held packages.

I tried fixing this by running
sudo apt-get install -f  
sudo dpkg –configure -a 
sudo apt-get clean
sudo apt-get autoclean

But it didn't work

What happens if you apt remove ike-server && apt install libreswan?  I believe the error is telling you that ike-server and libreswan cannot exist together, unless you've held packages back.

libreswan is already isntalled and unable to remvoe ike server

Temporarily remove libreswan and ike-server then try installing strongswan again.  You've caught a circular dependency

I had to use aptitude to install strongswan. That fixed the unmet dependencies. Thank you

I was able to install it by using aptitude
sudo aptitude install strongswan

